# How to properly reuse UICollectionView in a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView, where each cell contains a UICollectionView.

So when we scroll, the TableViewCell is reused, but what is the "proper" way to set/reset the UICollectionView ?

More specifically, When we init the TableViewCell, the collectionView is created and inited with a layout object.  During cell reuse, the collectionView is not re-alloced, so that layout object is not re-alloced nor changed either. However, will the same layout object work properly when you reuse it ?

Comment: The layout object should be fine to re-use.  You want to call reloadData on the collection view so that it shows the proper data for the cell.

Comment: This sounds like a UI nightmare in the making...

Comment: @jeffamaphone   Thanks Jeff.  It works, but I wondering if it is the best way and safe.  The layout object has many properties/states itself, if not get reset properly before reuse, it could potentially have problems.

Comment: @DuncanC  are you referring to the design of TableViewCell + inner CollectionView ?  what's your opinion ?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to collection views inside a table view. It sounds like a UI nightmare. In general you don't want one scrolling thing inside another. It makes controlling the inner object too difficult.

Comment: @DuncanC   True, but in my case, the table view is full screen, and each cell has a height around 200, so scrolling the collection view is pretty easy : )

Comment: @Andy how did you solve this?